# How to put text under image when window is resized or on mobile device?

Tags: html, css

When you resize the window the text get resized but what i want to happen it up to a certain point i want the text to get push below the image instead of it being squished.

This is what i have right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>In this example, the image will float to the left in the paragraph, and the text in the paragraph will wrap around the image.</p>

<p><img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  float: left;
}
  @media screen and (max-width:600px){
    p {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items:center;
    }
    p img {
      margin:10px;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>In this example, the image will float to the left in the paragraph, and the text in the paragraph will wrap around the image.</p>

<p><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="Pineapple" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">
  <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```